# How to test AtomicBoolean atomicity?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, concurrency

I'm writing unit tests for AtomicInteger and AtomicBoolean. They are going to be used as reference tests for testing emulations of these classes in objective-c, for use in translated projects.

The AtomicInteger test worked out well I think, basically by performing a predictable number of increment, decrement, add and subtract operations in a large number of for loops, each running in their own thread (and many threads per operation type). The actual operations start simultaneously using a CountDownLatch.

When all threads are done I assert by comparing the atomic integer with the expected integer value based on the number of threads, iterations per thread and the expected increase/decrease per iteration. This test passes.

**But how to test AtomicBoolean?** The basic operations are get and set so calling that many times in many threads and expecting the final result to be either true or false doesn't seem to make sense. The direction I'm thinking is to use two AtomicBooleans that should always have opposite values. Like this:

```
@Test
public void testAtomicity() throws Exception {

    // ====  SETUP  ====
    final AtomicBoolean booleanA = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    final AtomicBoolean booleanB = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    final int threadCount = 50;

    final int iterationsPerThread = 5000;

    final CountDownLatch startSignalLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final CountDownLatch threadsFinishedLatch = new CountDownLatch(threadCount);

    final AtomicBoolean assertFailed = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    // ====  EXECUTE: start all threads ====
    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {

        // ====  Create the thread  =====
        AtomicOperationsThread thread;
        thread = new AtomicOperationsThread("Thread #" + i, booleanA, booleanB, startSignalLatch, threadsFinishedLatch, iterationsPerThread, assertFailed);
        System.out.println("Creating Thread #" + i);

        // ====  Start the thread (each thread will wait until the startSignalLatch is triggered)  =====
        thread.start();
    }

    startSignalLatch.countDown();

    // ====  VERIFY: that the AtomicInteger has the expected value after all threads have finished  ====
    final boolean allThreadsFinished;
    allThreadsFinished = threadsFinishedLatch.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    assertTrue("Not all threads have finished before reaching the timeout", allThreadsFinished);
    assertFalse(assertFailed.get());

}

private static class AtomicOperationsThread extends Thread {

    // #####  Instance variables  #####

    private final CountDownLatch startSignalLatch;
    private final CountDownLatch threadsFinishedLatch;

    private final int iterations;

    private final AtomicBoolean booleanA, booleanB;

    private final AtomicBoolean assertFailed;

    // #####  Constructor  #####

    private AtomicOperationsThread(final String name, final AtomicBoolean booleanA, final AtomicBoolean booleanB, final CountDownLatch startSignalLatch, final CountDownLatch threadsFinishedLatch, final int iterations, final AtomicBoolean assertFailed) {

        super(name);
        this.booleanA = booleanA;
        this.booleanB = booleanB;
        this.startSignalLatch = startSignalLatch;
        this.threadsFinishedLatch = threadsFinishedLatch;
        this.iterations = iterations;
        this.assertFailed = assertFailed;
    }

    // #####  Thread implementation  #####

    @Override
    public void run() {

        super.run();

        // ====  Wait for the signal to start (so all threads are executed simultaneously)  =====
        try {
            System.out.println(this.getName() + " has started. Awaiting startSignal.");
            startSignalLatch.await();  /* Awaiting start signal */
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("The startSignalLatch got interrupted.", e);
        }

        // ====  Perform the atomic operations  =====
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {

            final boolean booleanAChanged;
            booleanAChanged = booleanA.compareAndSet(!booleanB.get(), booleanB.getAndSet(booleanA.get()));  /* Set A to the current value of B if A is currently the opposite of B, then set B to the current value of A */

            if (!booleanAChanged){
                assertFailed.set(true);
                System.out.println("Assert failed in thread: " + this.getName());
            }
        }

        // ====  Mark this thread as finished  =====
        threadsFinishedLatch.countDown();
    }
}
```

This works with one thread but fails with multiple. I guess this is because `booleanAChanged = booleanA.compareAndSet(!booleanB.get(), booleanB.getAndSet(booleanA.get()));` is not one atomic operation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm sure you have - but make sure you think about everything when testing this kind of low-level concurrency i.e. the hardware you're running on, the operating system, the JVM - it can all effect things like this and mean that tests that always pass in one context fail in another.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback. I assume you're referring to the AtomicInteger test, right? I'd like to be sure there are no false positives; Can you point out possible improvements for this approach and/or give examples of how something can go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would concentrate on `compareAndSet`, which is the real difference between an `AtomicBoolean` and an ordinary `boolean`.

For example, use `compareAndSet(false, true)` to control a critical region. Loop doing it until it returns false, then enter the critical region. In the critical region, do something that is very likely to fail if two or more threads run it at the same time. For example, increment a counter with a short sleep between reading the old value and writing the new value. At the end of the critical region, set the `AtomicBoolean` to false.

Initialize the `AtomicBoolean` to false, and `globalCounter` to zero before starting the threads.

```
for(int i=0; i<iterations; i++) {
  while (!AtomicBooleanTest.atomic.compareAndSet(false, true));
  int oldValue = AtomicBooleanTest.globalCounter;
  Thread.sleep(1);
  AtomicBooleanTest.globalCounter = oldValue + 1;
  AtomicBooleanTest.atomic.set(false);
}
```

At the end, the `globalCounter` value should be `t*iterations` where `t` is the number of threads.

The number of threads should be similar to the number the hardware can run simultaneously - and this is far more likely to fail on a multiprocessor than on a single processor. The highest risk of failure is immediately after the AtomicBoolean becomes false. All available processors should be simultaneously trying to get exclusive access to it, see it to be false, and atomically change it to true.

Comment: Interesting approach. It took me a while to grasp it, but it passes each time when it's like this (in each thread, with 500 threads):
 1. `while (!SUT.compareAndSet(false, true));`
 2. `int oldValue = AtomicBooleanTest.globalCounter;`
 3. `Thread.sleep(1);`
 4. `SUT.set(false);` 
When all threads are done, globalCounter should be 500. I assume this is what you had in mind, right?

Comment: @RolfW. I've incorporated your code in the answer, formatted and slightly modified. Although it might be worth experimenting, I would be surprised if it is useful to have a lot more threads than the hardware can run in parallel.

Comment: That makes sense, I think you're right. Since the test's logic is entirely CPU bound the computer would probably waste time managing threads that it could also use trying to get into a conflict. But I just realized that Thread.sleep() might be a factor too: I'd expect sleeping state to be idle time that could be utilized by adding more threads, is that right? That said, I did a quick test; When I run using exactly the number of available cores it utilizes nearly 100% - around the same when using 16 or 500 threads. That suggests sleep time is negligible. How does that work?

Comment: @RolfW. I don't know. What is the average time for an iteration?

Comment: With 2, 4, 6 and 7 threads it's consistently in the 1.1ms-1.2ms range, 4 threads being lowest at 1.1ms. 8 Threads is close to 2.0 (there are 8 cores). From there it goes up: 16 threads = 5.9, 32 threads = 7.4, etc.

So a thread count just under the number of available cores seems ideal and apparently this sleep time couldn't be utilized after all.

In all cases CPU use is  ~40%-45% in user mode and about the same in system mode. The java process reads around 300%. Fans are revving up.

Comment: Interestingly, each time after some time (probably 60sec or so) the java process increases to nearly 800% and CPU changes to 99% in user mode. From that moment on the fans are nearly silent. I didn't test thoroughly, but it appears that it doesn't affect the time per iteration (just tried once). Just out of curiosity, what would cause this change? Is this where the vm compiles to native code?

Comment: Here's a suggestion for testing the test. Add a thread that occasionally and arbitrarily sets the AtomicBoolean to false. If the test is a good test, you will get some failures.

Comment: A bit off-topic maybe, but do you have an idea what might be the reason for this change in CPU usage that happens after some time? Just curious.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's going to be harder to test this than an `AtomicInteger`, as you point out. The space of possible values is much smaller, and thus the space of possible things-that-can-go-wrong is much smaller. Since tests like this basically come down to luck (with lots of looping to increase your chances), it's going to be harder to hit that smaller target.

My recommendation would be to launch a lot of threads that have access to a single `AtomicBoolean`. Have each one of them do a CAS, and *only* if they succeed, atomically increment an `AtomicInteger`. When all the threads have finished, you should see just a single increment to that `AtomicInteger`. Then just rinse, lather, repeat.

Comment: Thanks yshavit. That test passes each time, even when running the test in a loop 1.000 times using 1.500 threads. Here's the code I used:

`final boolean valueUpdated;`
`valueUpdated = SUT.compareAndSet(true, false);`
    
`if (valueUpdated)
    valueUpdatedCount.incrementAndGet();`

Can I be confident that this isn't a false positive?

Comment: @RolfW. - Unfortunately, no.

Comment: @Stephen Currently I've implemented both yshavit's solution and the one proposed by Patricia Shanahan with many threads and iterations. AtomicBoolean will be used in ordinary mobile and web apps, nothing scientific or too mathematical. Having tested it like this, would you say there is a significant enough likelihood of bugs in apps like that? If unlikely then I'll settle on this. Otherwise, could you explain a bit more about your solution?

Comment: @RolfW. - My solution was wrong.  But that's not the point.  The point is that *no amount of black box testing ALONE* should be sufficient to make you confident that an atomic primitive has been implemented correctly.  The (hypothetical) bug may only show up in other tests ... or with a different compiler or OS version ... or on other hardware.  Concurrency bugs are like that.

Comment: You need to *combine* your testing with careful analysis of the source code ... preferably by a number of people including some who are skilled at low-level concurrency coding, and the language.

Comment: As others have said, concurrency bugs are ones you can't realistically test to full confidence -- you need to prove it analytically. That said, take a look at [AtomicBoolean's implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.java) and you'll see it's not very helpful. It comes down to a call to `unsafe.compareAndSwapInt`, which is native. Basically, this is a case where you have to trust the good folks at Oracle to have done their job right.

Answer (score 1):

It is four atomic operations.  Given you just want one boolean to be the inverse of the other,  just have one boolean and keep toggling that.  You can calculate the other from this value.