# How to test atomicboolean in method

Tags: java, unit-testing, atomicboolean

I want to test my method for thread-safety. For that I am using an atomicboolean. If it is true, then an exception is thrown. Now i want to test this function. What is the best way to test this function??

```
public void startProcess() {
      if(inProcess.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
              service.startProcess();
              inProcess.set(false);
      } else {
          throw new SomeNewException("Process running.");
      }
      inProcess.set(false);
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You forgot a closing parenthesis. Also, in Java, procedures are called *methods* rather than functions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414924/how-to-test-atomicboolean-atomicity

Comment: just launch 2 threads calling that method

Comment: take a look at https://dzone.com/articles/testing-multithreaded-code-in-java-1

Comment: You don’t need a test to see that this method is broken. At its end, there is a redundant `inProcess.set(false);`, which could overwrite the `true` state created by another thread between the two `inProcess.set(false);` statements. Besides that, the entire logic is questionable. How is the caller supposed to know that the call is invalid, i.e. a process is running? Even if you add a method like `isRunning()`, using it before the call would be subject to the check-then-act anti-pattern. And if the process may still run upon `startProcess()`’s return, as the name suggests, it’s even more broken…